# How to animate different selectors at the same time Jquery

Tags: jquery

Ok, I am very raw to jquery.  I am having trouble animating more than one selector at the same time. From what a learned so far you need an  $(document).ready() in which the the function(){} is entered.  So I have:

```
$(document) .ready(function(){
         $('.bio').animate(
             {
            left:'50px'
             }, 2500);
    });
```

And it works fine. However when i add a second selector with a different animation:

```
 $(document) .ready(function(){
         $('.bio').animate(
             {
            left:'50px'
             }, 2500);
**$('.web').animate(
         {
         right:'50px'
         }, 2000);**
    });
```

Nothing happens.  Why is this and how can a perform the animation?

Comment: what does `**` stand for?

Comment: i tried to bold to specify but instead it gave it the *

Comment: you cannot bold code - use comments // /* */ to comment code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very likely missing a `position` styling on your `.bio` and `.web` elements; animating an element's position requires a valid initial setting.

Example:

```
.bio, .web {
  position: relative;
}
```

Here's an example I've wired up that works as expected with relative positioned elements:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWwbqr

Comment: Ok so I took the bio and web class and created a general class for both of them to portfolio.  Then in css I modified the portfolio class to relative.  Your code, say on click but I took that out because I wanted the animation to occur when the page load.  The bio still work but the social does not.  I will use code pen so you have a better understanding of what I am talking about

Comment: I spoke to soon, it worked! Appreciate it! I was wondering is there any tools to use to learn more about jquery?

Comment: Glad it worked Eddie. I personally am a big fan of Pluralsight for e-learning; a lot of great courses, very interactive & based on real world scenarios.